# Button Background from resources

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, background

I have a few buttons that I add in my c# code. and I want to give them a background.

I want my application to work when I publish my application. How do I do that?
This is what i did but is not working:

```
var brush = new ImageBrush();                          
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/zwembad.png",UriKind.Relative));
plaatsen[counter].Background = brush;
```

It is working but when I publish and install it. Its not working?

How to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Are you certain you have that file (zwembad.png) on the target machine? Does it work if you use `SolidColorBrush` instead? Use MVVM :P...

Comment: You should be using XAML to define the UI, not procedural code to "create it". Learn to use WPF properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, C#/wpf:

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/yourimage.gif")));
brush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
btn.Background = brush;
```